# GHC Haskell tooling paths

Tags: haskell, ide, haskell-stack

What are the paths required to set up development environment with `GHC` project? Or more specifically, a `stack` managed `GHC` environment?

I'm confused about what is needed by `GHC`, `cabal`, `stack`, `ghc-mod` and `hdevtools`.

I know that `stack path` will print out managed paths but I think it prints them under different key names than environment variables or command line arguments which I need for `GHC` and other tools, so it's not directly useful to me.

For example, when working with typical `Java` project I need only to set `PATH`, `JAVA_HOME` and all tooling I need will work in this environment (for `Java` I often don't need separate `maven` repository for each project as linking is done differently).

Ideally I'd like to call `stack $SHELL` and have everything configured in environment (no `stack ghci` afterwards).

Comment: Doesn't `stack exec -- $SHELL` exactly do what you want?

Comment: I don't know. I get "Use of GHC's environment variable GHC_PACKAGE_PATH is incompatible with Cabal." error with `ghc-mod`

Comment: Have you tried using the custom ghc-mod cradle (https://github.com/DanielG/ghc-mod#custom-ghc-mod-cradle), try `echo "global\nuser" >> ghc-mod.package-db-stack` in the project directory